# Convert array of an array to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, object

i have an array like

```
var arrays = [  
  { "name": "aaa", "value": "bbb" },
  { "name": "ccc", "value": "ccc" },
  { "name": "ddd", "value": [ 'ee', 'ff', 'gg' ] }
]
```

but i need the convert it into

```
var arrays = [
  { "name": "aaa", "value": "bbb" },
  { "name": "ccc", "value": "ccc" },
  { "name": "ddd", "value": "ee, ff, gg" }
]
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: You should check this one - https://codezup.com/5-ways-to-convert-array-of-objects-to-object-in-javascript/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const modifiedArray = array.map(obj => {
      return {...obj, value: obj.value.toString()}
})
```

```js
var array = [  
  { "name": "aaa", "value": "bbb" },
  { "name": "ccc", "value": "ccc" },
  { "name": "ddd", "value": [ 'ee', 'ff', 'gg' ] }
]

const modifiedArray = array.map(obj => {
      return {...obj, value : obj.value.toString()}
})

console.log(modifiedArray)
```

Comment: Actually the whole naming convention is messed up too. We are dealing with one single array here, not multiple. But I do like the functional approach. This is nice.

Comment: Great use of the `rest` operator @kritiz! The first time I've seen it used on an object.

Comment: @PeterKA, First time I got a compliment on stackoverflow , thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. This is one of them:

```js
const array = [  
  { "name": "aaa", "value": "bbb" },
  { "name": "ccc", "value": "ccc" },
  { "name": "ddd", "value": [ 'ee', 'ff', 'gg' ] }
];

array.forEach(el=>Array.isArray(el.value) && (el.value=el.value.join(" ,")))

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Though this will only check 1 layer deep, also I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.

```js
const arrays = [
  { name: "aaa", value: "bbb" },
  { name: "ccc", value: "ccc" },
  { name: "ddd", value: ["ee", "ff", "gg"] }
];

const converted = arrays.map(value => {
  let convert = { ...value };
  for (const key in convert) {
    if (Array.isArray(convert[key])) {
      convert[key] = convert[key].join(", ");
    };
  };
  return convert;
});

console.log(converted);
```

Answer (score 1):

A tweak on @kritiz's answer ...

```
array.map( obj => ({...obj, value : [].concat(obj.value).join(', ')}) );
```

**DEMO**

```js
let array = [  
  { "name": "aaa", "value": "bbb" },
  { "name": "ccc", "value": "ccc" },
  { "name": "ddd", "value": [ 'ee', 'ff', 'gg' ] }
]

let newArray = array.map( obj => ({...obj, value : [].concat(obj.value).join(', ')}) );

console.log( newArray )
```